# Get Masonry to update heights once Twitter widgets have loaded

Tags: jquery, twitter, widget, jquery-masonry, masonry

I have a masonry grid using http://masonry.desandro.com and inside two of the boxes I have standard Twitter feed widgets from https://twitter.com/settings/widgets

Currently the Twitter widgets load after Masonry has looked at the heights of the boxes, so when the Twitter feeds load, and increase the height of the boxes that they are in, the boxes then overlap with the ones below.

I believe in order to stop this from happening I need to call msnry.layout(); after the Twitter feeds have loaded. (http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#layout)

However, I have been unable to find a way to detect when the feeds have loaded, and thus run msnry.layout();

Advice appreciated.

Comment: There is a `rendered` event, but that seems to fire too soon. The only way that I could get it to work was to use setTimeout. Not ideal though.